# Ошибка при попытке запустить jar файл

Tags: java, maven, логирование, log4j

Есть проект maven , он компилируется в Intelli Idea. После чего я компилирую его с помощью maven и создаю jar файл. Который при запуске(в консоле) выдает ошибку:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger   at
>
> Main.(Main.java:10)

Ругается на логирование, без логирования работает и пишет то что мне нужно.

XML файл:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>Time</groupId>
<artifactId>GreetTime</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>GreetJar</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.12</log4j.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>${log4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com</id>
        <url>http://onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Код программы:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

/**
 * Created by Alex on 07.09.2016.
 */
 public class Main {

public static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Main.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    log.info("Create Greet object");
    Greet gr = new Greet();
    gr.getLocale();
    gr.gethours();
    ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Bundle", gr.myLocale);
    log.info("Switch language");
    gr.showMessage(bundle);
    log.info("Conclusion greetings");
    log.info("Terminate program");

   }
 }
```

Судя из того что я нашел в интернете, мне надо править мути в мэйнфесте и как-то создавать lo4j.jar , осталось понять как.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

проблема в том, что loj4j.jar не лежит рядом с твоим джарником и не указан в classPath.

1) можно добавить в `classPath` как ключ, либо в манифесте

```
Сlass-Path: log4j.jar
```

2) в `pom` добавить

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

выполнить команду `mvn package`, у тебя в `target` соберется 2 файла: один со всеми зависимостями (`GreetTime-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar`), а другой без них (`GreetTime-1.0.jar`)

тот, что со всеми зависимостями будет работать и не потребует добавление библиотек в `classPath`

Comment: У меня при запуске файла с зависимостями вылетает такое no main manifest attribute, in D:\Programming\Projects\Java\Greeting\target\GreetTime-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Стало быть проблемы с манифестом, подскажите как правильно его оформить?
вот мой
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: log4j.jar
Main-Class: Main

Comment: При таком вариант введения команды он запустился
java -cp GreetTime-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar Main

Comment: @AlexanderBogomaz проблем нет теперь?

Comment: Нет, нету, по сути все работает, просто приходится писать название класса в конце, может подскажите ещё как запускать тесты при сборке ?Тут или я вопрос создал новый.[http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/567253/maven-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5-jar-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0]