# maven запуск тестов при сборке jar файла

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, maven, jar

Есть проект maven , при сборке создается jar файл который успешно выводит нужное сообщение. Нужно что бы при сборке проходили тесты, что надо добавить в xml файл для этого? Вот мой xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>Time</groupId>
<artifactId>GreetTime</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>GreetJar</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.12</log4j.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>src.java.main.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Создается test.jar файл

Comment: чтобы одна команда mvn package запускала тесты ?  нельзя ли использовать mvn verify package ?

Comment: Запустил,сложился новый jar файл, чем он отличается от прошлого? И я добавил maven-surefire-plugin он создал Test.jar это не значит что мои тесты проходят и запускаются при сборке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в pom добавить

```
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*IntegrationTest.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>none</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*IntegrationTest.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>

                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

создать класс

```
    import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class IntegrationTest {
    @org.junit.Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("setUp");

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {

        System.out.println("tearDown ");

    }

    @Test
    public void testfirst() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("testfirst");

    }
    @Test
    public void testsecond() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("testsecond");
//        Assert.fail();
    }

}
```

выполнить команду  `mvn clean verify package`

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ GreetTime ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\\IdeaProjects\GreetJar\target\GreetTime-1.0.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (default) @ GreetTime ---
[INFO] META-INF/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/MANIFEST.MF already added, skipping
[INFO] org/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/MANIFEST.MF already added, skipping
[INFO] org/ already added, skipping
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\IdeaProjects\GreetJar\target\GreetTime-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
[INFO] META-INF/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/MANIFEST.MF already added, skipping
[INFO] org/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/MANIFEST.MF already added, skipping
[INFO] org/ already added, skipping
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (integration-test) @ GreetTime ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\\IdeaProjects\GreetJar\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running IntegrationTest
setUp
testsecond
tearDown 
setUp
testfirst
tearDown 
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.11 sec

Results :

Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ GreetTime ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ GreetTime ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ GreetTime ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory IdeaProjects\GreetJar\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ GreetTime ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ GreetTime ---
[INFO] Skipping execution of surefire because it has already been run for this configuration
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ GreetTime ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (default) @ GreetTime ---
[INFO] META-INF/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/MANIFEST.MF already added, skipping
[INFO] org/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/MANIFEST.MF already added, skipping
[INFO] org/ already added, skipping
[INFO] Building jar: \IdeaProjects\GreetJar\target\GreetTime-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
[INFO] META-INF/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/MANIFEST.MF already added, skipping
[INFO] org/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/MANIFEST.MF already added, skipping
[INFO] org/ already added, skipping
[WARNING] Artifact Time:GreetTime:jar:jar-with-dependencies:1.0 already attached to project, ignoring duplicate
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.373s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Sep 17 13:40:45 MSK 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/265M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Спасибо за очень содержательный ответ. 
1)У меня выдает [ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
  C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\..\lib\tools.jar
Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
In most cases you can change the location of your Java
installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
Мой JAVA_HOME настроен нормально(
2) После команды clean проект не запускается приходится его настраивать по новой.

Comment: неверно настроены переменные окружения. ответ на данный вопрос вот тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585380/maven-unable-to-locate-the-javac-compiler-in  посмотри что в интернете пишут и как решают, чтобы не спамить тут